# End user wants to add languages dynamically to his website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, localization, razor

We have to build an event registration website for our client in ASP.NET using C#.
One of the requirements is that the client wants to add new foreign languages to his website himself using en excel file. I know how to make a website multilingual in Visual Studio, but I have no idea how to generate a resource file based on an excel file in code.
I also noticed VS generates a second file called Resource.en.designer.cs but I can't find any documentation how to generate that file either.

btw, the enduser is anything but IT-related. He knows his way around excel though (obviously).

Any help is appreciated!

Yoeri

EDIT:
!Robert Levy Provided a good method!
HOW TO:

STEP 1:
Read the excel file (using an OleDBAdapter was the best method for me, as you can use column headers etc)
Write the language to a txt file in this format:
KEY=TRANSLATION
no spaces or anything else

STEP 2:
Locate ResGen.exe on your computer (it comes with Visual Studio, so look somewhere like c:\program files\visual studio\sdk... however I found it @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ResGen.exe)

STEP 3:

Invoke the exe with Process.Start("resgen.exe")
*hint: use ProcesStartInfo for easy argument and preferences settings*

(STEP 4:)

Move the file to your desired location (I find the App_GlobalResources works perfectly)

STEP 5:

Set the user currentUIculture to your desired culture!

Comment: sehe - huh?  this is clearly a coding question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResGen.exe will compile resource files for you.  You could either get him to deliver text files in the format used by that tool or write your own code that extracts from excel to generate the text files.  Then just invoke this EXE and deploy your newly generated resource DLL.  I am assuming you already know how to read things from resource files and use the appropriate one based on user preference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx

Comment: I never invoked an exe from code before, but i thrust there's plenty of information for doing that around here.
I will definitly look into it. 
Thanks!

Comment: @yoeri - yup, easy stuff.  just look at the various static Start methods on the Process class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: nice.  nobody else actually answered the question yet i also end up with a downvote somehow.

Comment: Not my fault.. I gave you the up one :p
Someone else suggested to just build the xml file manually. He guessed the overhead is standard and always the same so one could just copy it in a template or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I finally did it using ResGen. Took me a while to locate the .exe, but it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably one place where you would like to use resources from database rather than simple resx files. It would be easier just to populate database table(s) with Excel data than transforming it to standard resx file (it could be a problem in the future if MS decided to modify file format).

So I would suggest you to write your own [ResourceReader which would load strings from database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Custom_Resource_Reader.aspx) (it could load it directly from Excel as well, but for many reasons I wouldn't recommend this method).

Comment: using ResGen proved much faster :p

Answer (score -1):

You should ask your end-user if they really have to get another language 'on the fly' and how many languages they expect they are going to add.

Otherwise, e-mailing the Excel file to you and manually creating the resource file might be by far the cheapest solution....

Comment: I know, he admitted he won't be using it a lot, but he really wants it.

Comment: That's fine, it is a requirement.  You just have to show him the cost and ask him whether it needs to be in scope and bill accordingly.

Comment: The cost doesn't matter to him. It definitely needs to be in scope. Believe me, I tried to talk to him to see into alternatives (like mailing me the excel or anything) but he is very stubborn.